# What are some solutions for avoiding the select(n+1) issue in Doctrine2 for aggregate count fields?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two entities, User and Place, and have a many-to-many relationship between them in order to facilitate the concept of a user favoriting a place.

As part of the feature, I would like for the Place entity to contain a field which gives me the total number of users who have favorited it. I do not need the user entities themselves.

Reading the documentation, I've found several solutions, but I don't particularly like any of them.

**Aggregate Field**

Using this solution, I would simply define an integer field on the Venue entity that is updated as favorites are added and removed. Thus, the value is not calculated on-the-fly and instead is retrieved as any other field would be.

I dislike this approach as there are issues with concurrency and it makes the concept unnecessarily complex to manage in code.

**Eager Loading**

Using this method, I would eagerly load the relationship as a bidirectional association so that the Place would load each User entity that has favorited it as part of the initial querying process. To get the count, I simply ask the collection for its count().

This results in fewer queries, but the amount of data retrieved is too much and does not scale well over time.

**Extra Lazy Loading**

This is what I am currently using. It is similar to the Eager Loading solution in that I ensure the relationship is bi-directional and simply ask the collection for its count(), but using the extra lazy fetch mode doctrine is intelligent enough to only issue a COUNT() query rather than retrieve the entire list of users associated with the Place entity.

The drawback here is that if I am loading N Place entities, I need N+1 queries as each Place will issue a separate COUNT() query.

**Ideal Solution**

My ideal solution would be to find a way to tell Doctrine to perform the first query to load the collection and then a second query to load all counts for the IDs within the collection and then populate the fields in their respective entities.

I have not found a way to do this easily.

Does anyone have any examples of this or are there other solutions for solving this problem that I may be overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

if you know how to write your query in sql, you can do it in doctrine.

see this answer for reference:
[Symfony2, Doctrine2 query - select with IF and COUNT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25547629/symfony2-doctrine2-query-select-with-if-and-count)

Comment: Writing the query isn't the issue so much as wrangling Doctrine into understanding what to do with the data. I want it to populate an entity field. I want to avoid ad-hoc scalar queries and data munging if at all possible. It seems it may not be, alas.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a similar DQL:

```
SELECT p place, COUNT(u) cnt FROM YourBundle:Place p
                LEFT JOIN p.users u
```

Note that results array elements are in the form (each is an array):

```
array(
 'place' => your hydrated object (in your case the place),
 'cnt' => your aggregated field (in your case the number of users),
)
```

Comment: Which is frustrating because I don't want it to be separate. I want Doctrine to understand how to populate it as an entity field without being so expensive query-wise.

Comment: You're hoping doctrine to be too clever ;) Anyway your ideal solution uses two queries, but mine uses only 1. Can i ask what's the problem the two being separate keys ?

Comment: The issue is that I am returning entities to be serialized. Now I have some other random value that isn't part of an entity that *someone* has to deal with. So, either I now loop through all results and re-organize the data to make sense or my clients get a clunky experience whereby a collection of Place entities is not just a collection of Place entities, it's a collection of arrays where one key is the place and then N other keys are fields I wasn't smart enough to be able to make Doctrine play well with. Certainly not a catastrophe, but I'm forever in search of a better way!

Comment: I see. Well I don't think you'll find a 'lazy' way of doing this. I also look for such a solution!

Comment: [Custom Hydrators](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#custom-hydration-modes) can be possible solution.